# HP printer not printing

Tags: macos, printer, printing

I am running macOS 10.15 Catalina and have a DeskJet 6940 printer that has stopped working. I can successfully send a job to the printer.

It successfully runs through the printer, positioning the cartridge, starting and stopping the paper feed as expected. Nothing shows up on the paper (no smudges or marks of any kind). The problem occurs for both color and B/W jobs. I have tried both old and new cartridges.

I am running macOS, and I tried from various MacBooks. I have not touched the printer driver. It feels like something simple, but I have tried everything I can think of (power cycling, different computer sources). I would appreciate any suggestions you might have.

Comment: What happens when you print a diagnostic test page? Press and hold the Power button.
While holding the Power button, press the Cancel (X) button, and then release both buttons.

Comment: Could it be HP has intentionally disabled it? https://gizmodo.com/judge-rules-hp-must-face-lawsuit-over-disabled-printers-1850742791

Comment: @hdhondt: A blank page is printed.

Comment: @gizmodo.com: How could a figure that out?

Comment: Either all jets are blocked (unlikely) or something else has failed catastrophically. If it's under warranty, contact the supplier; otherwise, a new printer is probably your best bet.